# Bootstrap navbar in reactjs doesnt fit whole width of screen

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap using bootstrap in reactjs framework.while executing this code navbar doesn't display full width in the screen I need nav bar foe whole width

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
//import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class ClientProfile extends Component {

    render(){
        return(
            <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-light">          
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    Nav
                </a>
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"> How it Works </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav> 
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using any Container? Post the parent component where you are using this component.

Comment: you can customize css according to you.

Comment: Are you using only `bootstrap` or `react-bootstrap`?

Comment: can you please provide a working demo? Information provided here is not enough to understand your problem.